# Ansible - Replace all text between two specified lines in file with ansible.builtin.replace module

Tags: regex, text, replace, ansible

I've been trying to replace all text between two specified lines in a configuration file using Ansible.

With this task block, I simply want to remove all text between the two specified lines. In the next task, I'll be adding new configurations between those same two lines.

Appreciate any guidance/assistance, thanks!

```
      - name: Remove all lines between specified lines in hosts file.
        ansible.builtin.replace:
          path: /etc/hosts
          after: "^#BeginEntries$"
          before: "^#EndEntries$"
          regexp: '.*'
          replace: ""
          backup: yes
```

This current task block doesn't seem to be matching my after/before. Nothing is changed, even though those two lines do exist in the specified file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ansible, but I did get a Regex to work using `\n` in this [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tJDQnU/1).  In the left column there is a "FLAVOR" section, if you know what flavor of Regex is used in Ansible, then you can change it there and experiment till something works.

Comment: Thanks! Andrew's answer below seems to indicate the same. Using `\n` may just be the trick. I like the solution posed with blockinfile though, so will try that first and run with it if it works as intended =)

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to replace content between those lines, you should use [ansible.builtin.blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) module with `state: present` and replace it right away! See:

**text.txt**

```
123
#BeginEntries
bad_entry_1
bad_entry_2
#EndEntries
321
```

**playbook.yaml**

```yaml
- name: Replace block
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Replace block
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/text.txt"
        marker: "#{mark}"
        marker_begin: "BeginEntries"
        marker_end: "EndEntries"
        state: present
        content: |
          my awsome content with

          even

          multiple

          blank

          lines
```

Output:

```
❯ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i localhost,

PLAY [Replace block] *************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Replace block] *************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

❯ cat text.txt
123
#BeginEntries
my awsome content with

even

multiple

blank

lines
#EndEntries
321
```

In the example above, we define marker itself (starting #), and then BeginEntries and EndEntries as begin and end blocks. There is no need to use regex because in this case - match would be exact.

If you really want this to be a 2-step operation (remove and then modify), you can use this module too, but with caveat that you'll end up with empty string between markers (as per docs, empty "content" or "block" results in `state: absent`)

```
- name: Remove block
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Remove block
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/text.txt"
        marker: "#{mark}"
        marker_begin: "BeginEntries"
        marker_end: "EndEntries"
        state: present
        content: "{{ '\n' }}"
```

Then output of text.txt would be

```
❯ cat text.txt
123
321
#BeginEntries

#EndEntries
```

Regarding your example with replace module, it seems that "^" and "$" markers [are not working in multiline mode in before and after params](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-before) in replace module, and that might be a reason why you aren't getting the result you expect. You can work around this behavior by using newlines, like this:

```
      ansible.builtin.replace:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/text.txt"
        after: "\n#BeginEntries\n"
        before: "\n#EndEntries\n"
        regexp: '.*'
        replace: ""
```

That will result in

```
123
#BeginEntries


#EndEntries
321
```

But I still strongly recommend using blockinfile module, since it's basically made for your usecase.

Comment: Thankyou! I will test this in the next day or two with blockinfile, and report back either way =)

Comment: blockinfile is definitely the way to go. Got it working as expected that way :) I was able to get replace working also with your suggestions, but replace seemed inconsistent. On one pass, it actually blew out `#EndEntries` as well. On another pass, it added multiple replace strings between after/before, instead of just one... Odd and inconsistent results with replace module, but it did work more often than not. Thanks for the help! Going with blockinfile for sure :)